Differential operators and iterations of tangent bundle
Is there a relationship between higher order differential operators and higher tangent bundle viewed as bundle on the base manifold?

Higher order tangent bundles describe higher order derivatives of parametrized curves in a manifold. To describe higher order derivatives of (say) scalar functions on a manifold (and hence higher order differential operators acting on them) you need jet bundles.

Your original question was quite vague. It sounds like you have something more specific in mind. Perhaps you should update your question to make it as precise as possible.
